# How to use setw with cin to insert spaces automatically after user enters first number

Tags: c++

I want the user to **enter two numbers** but I want them **like** following

```
cout<< "Enter two numbers quantity and amount";
```

User should enter 1st number under quantity and 2nd under amount e.g

> Enter two numbers **quantity** and **amount**
>
> ```
>                   12           13
> ```

Means after first number there comes space automatically and then user enter next number, **I want the compiler to insert spaces on same line as soon as user enters first number**. How can I do that in CPP, I am using CodeBlocks. What I am doing is

```
   cin >> i; 
   cin >> setw(15) >>j;
```

But it's not working. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Do you mean you want to print some spaces as soon as the user enters the first digit. or that  you want to force the user to input some spaces in between digits? (The first  isn't really possible in Standard C++).

Comment: I want compiler to insert spaces on same line as soon as user enters first number

Comment: That isn't possible with standard streams. On most systems, the shell doesn't send the input to your program until the user enters a newline (hits return). You may be able to do it with some platform specific input/output functions; what platform are you targeting?

Comment: `while ( std::cin >> i) { }` will skip white-space by default, not sure what you're trying to achieve ?